# How to reference a file from inside of a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

What's the correct way to find the absolute path to a file from within a gem? In other words, let's say I'm in `gem_install_path/mygem/lib/mygem.rb`, and I want the path to `gem_install_path/mygem/foo/`. What's the correct way to get that?

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Isn't `/mygem/foo/` already an absolute path?

Comment: @sawa Sure but it is useless because there won't be a `/mygem` directory. There will however be a `/some/unknown/path/to/the/gem/mygem/foo` directory. The question is clearly how do you get the `gem_install_path` part from inside the gem.

Comment: Thanks @mu - I'm thinking there's a Gem method but I can't find it and google is impossible for this one.

Comment: Why you need to know that path from outside of the Gem? What do you try to achieve? I would argue that if you need to know internals of a Gem, then the Gem should have a method to provide it.

Comment: @spickerman - yes but then how does the gem method do that?

Comment: @pguardiario: I did not say that it is impossible. I only think it breaks the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and should not be done, because it creates a dependency between your code and the internals of a very specific version of that Gem. E.g. what if the maintainer of the Gem changes file names in the next version?

Comment: @spickerman - I think there's a misunderstanding, it's my gem and I'm trying to get the absolute path to a file relative to the gem base path from inside of that gem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not clear which path you want, but probably one of the following will give you what you want:

```
Gem.loaded_specs["mygem"].base_dir
Gem.loaded_specs["mygem"].full_gem_path
Gem.loaded_specs["mygem"].gem_dir
Gem.loaded_specs["mygem"].gems_dir
```

Comment: Yes, `gem_dir` was what I was looking for. Thanks.